# Javascript Dead button

Tags: javascript

I am working on a browser button style game, but when i get to a certain point there is a dead button, and i cannot find any problems with it

```
function L2right1() {
if(hasSword == true){
 q.innerHTML = "You walk down the hall";
 option1.setAttribute("onclick","stabwall1()");
 option1.innerHTML = "Keep walking";
 option2.setAttribute("onclick", "goback1()");
 option2.innerHTML = "Go back";
}
if(hasSword == false){
    q.innerHTML = "You end up in a small room with nothing but a hole in the wall.";
    option1.setAttribute("onclick","goback1()");
    option1.innerHTML = "Go back";
    option2.setAttribute("onclick", "trylookaround()");
    option2.innerHTML = "Look around";
   }
}
function stabwall1() {
    if(opendoor == true){
     q.innerHTML = "burp";
     option1.setAttribute("onclick","continue2()");
     option1.innerHTML = "Enter the room";
     option2.setAttribute("onclick", "goback1()");
     option2.innerHTML = "Go back";
    }
    if(opendoor == false){
        q.innerHTML = "You end up in a small room with nothing but a hole in the wall. it looks like you daggar may fit in it";
        option1.setAttribute("onclick","goback1()");
        option1.innerHTML = "Stab wall ig";
        option2.setAttribute("onclick", "goback1()");
        option2.innerHTML = "Go back";
       }
```

when i run this, the button simply will not work, and if i reference another function, it works.
is there a problem here or is it something wrong with the variable perhaps? in that case, i could send the full code

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work" and "if I reference another function"?  You're leaving out way too many details, so no one can help you.  Also, on an unrelated note, you never need to write `if(opendoor == true)` or `if(opendoor==false)`; you can just write `if (opendoor) { ... } else { ...`.

Comment: Please add a working snippet somewhere, otherwise it's difficult to figure out the issue and the solution.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As a new user, I'd recommend you review [ask] to get tips on forming your questions in a way that enables the community to assist you.  Could you create a [mcve] as a snippet in the question?  While that may take some effort, it is the easiest and best way to get engagement from the community in solving your problem.  Good luck, and happy coding!